# Count indirect method calls Mockito

Tags: java, methods, count, mockito

I'm having problems with counting method calls with Mockito. Problem is that the method whos calls I want to count is called in test class indirectly by other method. Here is the code:

```
public class ClassForTest {
    private Integer value;

    public void doSmth() {
        prepareValue("First call");
        prepareValue("Second call");
        prepareValue("Third call");
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    protected void prepareValue(String msg) {
        System.out.println("This is message: " + msg);
        value++;
    }
}
```

And the test class:

```
public class ClassForTestTest extends TestCase {
    @Test
    public void testDoSmth() {
        ClassForTest testMock = mock(ClassForTest.class);
        doNothing().when(testMock).prepareValue(anyString());
        testMock.doSmth();
        verify(testMock, times(3)).prepareValue(anyString());
    }
}
```

Having such exception:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
classForTest.prepareValue(<any>);
-> at org.testing.ClassForTestTest.testDoSmth(ClassForTestTest.java:24)

However, there were other interactions with this mock:
-> at org.testing.ClassForTestTest.testDoSmth(ClassForTestTest.java:21)
```

Any ideas please. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will work.  Using a `spy` calls the underlying method.  Make sure `value` is initialized first.

```
    @Test
    public void testDoSmth() {
        ClassForTest testMock = spy(new ClassForTest());
        testMock.doSmth();
        verify(testMock, times(3)).prepareValue(anyString());
    }

    public class ClassForTest {
        private Integer value = 0;

        public void doSmth() {
            prepareValue("First call");
            prepareValue("Second call");
            prepareValue("Third call");
            System.out.println(value);
        }

        protected void prepareValue(String msg) {
            System.out.println("This is message: " + msg);
            value++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I've tried spy but in the wrong way as I see.

Answer (score 4):

This is an indication that you need some refactoring to improve your design. A single class should be fully testable without needing to mock out pieces of it. Whatever pieces you feel need to be mocked out should be extracted into one or more collaborating objects. **Don't** fall into the trap of partial mocks. Listen to what the tests are telling you. Your future self will thank you.

Comment: Yes I understand it. But in real app prepareValue method calls oracle stored procedure so I can't test it on inmemory db. So I'm just trying to count the number of calls.

Comment: I agree but sometimes you are dealing with legacy, 3rd party code, or doing a complex integration test and need to use a spy.

Comment: @catdog: What `prepareValue()` does is irrelevant to the fact that the tests are guiding you in a specific direction, but the fact that it's calling a stored procedure just about proves my point that it should be pulled out to a collaborator. That's not something that should be mixed in with your logic in this way.

Comment: @Gnon: That's certainly true, but there's no indication that that's the case here.

Comment: @catdog I added another answer if you are curious about how to refactor out a delegate you can mock.

Comment: @RyanStewart But if that's certainly true your claim is not general.

Answer (score 1):

You are mocking the tested class. Mocking is intended for the dependencies of a tested class, rather than the class itself.

I suspect what you want is `Mockito.spy()`. However, this is *partial mocking* which the Mockito Javadoc recommends against.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to refactor for testability, you can do the following:

```
@Test
public void testDoSmth() {
    Preparer preparer = mock(Preparer.class);
    ClassForTest cft = new ClassForTest(preparer);
    cft.doSmth();
    verify(preparer, times(3)).prepareValue(anyString());
}

public class ClassForTest {
    private final Preparer preparer;

    public ClassForTest(Preparer preparer) {
        this.preparer = preparer;
    }

    public void doSmth() {
        preparer.prepareValue("First call");
        preparer.prepareValue("Second call");
        preparer.prepareValue("Third call");
        System.out.println(preparer.getValue());
    }
}

public class Preparer {
    private Integer value = 0;

    public void prepareValue(String msg) {
        System.out.println("This is message: " + msg);
        value++;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a quite reasonable refactoring. But it is a question what is better to create many Preparers or to use partial mocking.